# Bash: Reference a folder that has not been created yet

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I would like to have a script that is able to view the /Users/CurrentlyLoggedinUser/Pictures directory, and when the logged in user creates a folder inside using the GUI, the script automatically creates two additional sub directories.

Example being the user creates a new folder using the GUI called "National Parks" inside the /Users/CurrentlyLoggedinUser/Pictures and the script automatically creates two sub folders called "Original" and "Edited"

The script would need to reference a folder that is not yet created which is where I am running into trouble.

Comment: What have you tried — show us your best effort.  Please read up about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  How are you planning to detect that the user creates a sub-directory?  Are you on Linux?  If so, can you use iNotify?

Comment: Thank you for the response it is my first post and I will definitely read that article. The question that you asked "How are you planning to detect that the user creates a sub-directory?" is a great question that I have as well. I am working on Mac OS and I am unfamiliar with iNotify for Linux, but ill see if there is something similar now knowing that is a piece to the puzzle.

Comment: Looks like fswatch can monitor that folder for any changes.

Comment: That looks very plausible.

Comment: Thanks for the patience! I was fooling around with this the other day. fswatch has been installed and using this syntax fswatch -d ~/Pictures | cut -d/ -f5 I am able to create a folder and cut the output of fswatch to get the name of the new folder. However, I am now running into the issue where fswatch spits out 3 lines of reporting per single folder creation.